# TWebBrowser memory leaks and access violations

Tags: c++builder, twebbrowser

My C++Builder application (RAD Studio XE4) is leaking memory.  In doing some debugging, I tracked down the cause to the TWebBrowser component on a form that's created and destroyed; apparently, the TWebBrowser or one of the objects it creates is leaking memory.

I've also seem some strange access violations: if this form with its TWebBrowser has ever been created, and if a modal dialog is currently open, then a Group Policy refresh (whether from Windows' periodic background updates or from calling `gpupdate`) causes an access violation.  Presumably the incompletely deleted TWebBrowser is trying to reapply some Internet Explorer settings and chasing a pointer to a deleted object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in C++Builder and in its handling of DelphiInterface properties.  I've observed this in XE4 and XE6; other versions are untested.

Apparently this is the same issue that's described at [QC#106829](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=106829); Delphi's handling of IDispatch properties calls `AddRef` without properly calling `Release`.

A workaround is to avoid the IDispatch `Document` property and instead use the protected getter to get the document:

```
_di_IDispatch GetDocument(TWebBrowser *browser)
{
  // Hack to change access modifiers on TWebBrowser.  Since accessing the public
  // property doesn't work, we'll access the protected getter.
  class TWebBrowserHack : public TWebBrowser
  {
  public:
    _di_IDispatch GetDocument() { return Get_Document(); }
  };

  return static_cast<TWebBrowserHack*>(browser)->GetDocument();
}
```